# Samsung chromebook and the new Wacom intuos pen and touch tablet

Tags: 12.04, drivers, samsung, wacom, chromebook

I would like to use my new wacon Intuos pen and touch tablet with my Chromebook.

I installed Ubuntu Unity 12.04 on my samsung chromebook. I works well. I have seen a that there is some kind of wacom driver or something already installed with this version of ubuntu (Wacom Graphics Tablet). Saddly, when I plug the device... nothing. It powers on but that is all.

Comment: I looked up on the forum but I couln't figure it out

Comment: In the terminal, I did 
 
lsusb